# Difference between types of solutions in network matchings?

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory

So there are so many different types of [solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Definitions): pareto, stable, rank-maximal, etc. etc.
How do anyone know which one to use for any given problem? Particularly when some of them may not exist?
And then how do I know what algorithm to use?

Comment: I am familiar with Pareto fronts, but I am not sure what you mean by the other categories. Can you supply some definitions for context, please?

Comment: See here for context! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Definitions